# Hibernate ORA-02292: integrity constraint (ROOT.SYS_C007062) violated - child record found

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many

I following have hibernate entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "News")
public final class News implements Serializable, IEntity {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 3773281197317274020L;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "NEWS_SEQ_GEN", sequenceName = "NEWS_SEQ")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "NEWS_SEQ_GEN")
@Column(name = "NEWS_ID", precision = 0)
private Long newsId; // Primary key

@Column(name = "TITLE")
private String title;

@Column(name = "SHORT_TEXT")
private String shortText;

@Column(name = "FULL_TEXT")
private String fullText;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "CREATION_DATE")
private Date creationDate;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "MODIFICATION_DATE")
private Date modificationDate;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "NEWS_ID", updatable = false, referencedColumnName = "NEWS_ID")
@OrderBy("creationDate ASC")
private List<Comment> commentsList;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "NEWS_TAG", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "NEWS_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "TAG_ID") })
private Set<Tag> tagSet;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "NEWS_AUTHOR", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "NEWS_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "AUTHOR_ID") })
private Set<Author> author;
```

And the second:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "COMMENTS_SEQ", sequenceName = "COMMENTS_SEQ")
@Entity
@Table(name = "Comments")
public class Comment implements Serializable, IEntity {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 3431305873409011465L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "COMMENTS_SEQ")
@Column(name = "COMMENT_ID", precision = 0)
private Long commentId; // Primary key

@Column(name = "NEWS_ID")
private Long newsId;

@NotEmpty
@NotNull
@Column(name = "COMMENT_TEXT")
private String commentText;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "CREATION_DATE")
private Date creationDate;
```

When I'm trying to remove entity News, I get the exception ORA-02292: integrity constraint (ROOT.SYS_C007062) violated - child record found. So, if I remove the property  "updatable = false" it tries to set nullable fields into property Comment. What is my mistake? Please, help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your news records have a one to one or one to many relation with comments. You most likely did not specifcy a CACASDE ON DELETE clause while defining your table. in order to delete entity NEWS you have to make sure that all of its related comments records are deleted or are referencing another NEWS record. 
basicaly the definition of the ORA 02292 exception.

Comment: Where should cascade delete be specified? I set this property inside the onetomany annotation! And also 2 other relationships work correctly (tagSet and author)

Comment: Normally you would add a cascade clause in your DDL (Data Definition language)

Comment: Look cascade on delete is something you **can** do, but you have to think about it, in the context of your system is this acceptable ? Let me give you an example: in a billing system there can be a record for table CUSTOMER and multiple records for table BILL. Do you think it would be a smart thing to delete all bills whenever a customer is deleted ?, personally i think not, the bill may not have been payed for example. This is something you need to think about before actually inclusing in your DDL. It's simple, the record you are trying to delete has child records you need to delete.